# How to use DependencyProperty in Maui?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

I am trying to use Dependency Property in Maui, but it looks like it is not available with Maui. It is showing reference missing error. How can I resolve it? Same code is working in xamarin and uwp but in Maui it is showing reference error for DependencyProperty keyword.

Following is the code example:

```
  public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius(Button element)
    {
        return (CornerRadius)element.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "CornerRadius",
            typeof(CornerRadius),
            typeof(ButtonHelperClass),
            new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(5))
            );
```

Answer (score 7):

We can use BindableProperty at place of DependencyProperty

```
public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius(Button element)
{
    return (CornerRadius)element.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
    BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
        "CornerRadius",
        typeof(CornerRadius),
        typeof(ButtonHelperClass),
        new CornerRadius(5)
        );
```